# Change the allowDefinition attribute in web.config file

Tags: .net, iis, authentication, web-config

I've created a Login System in C# according to this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx

I have an specific hierarchy of files. My web.config is, obviously, in my root folder, but the application that requires the login is on a nested folder. If I create a new web.config inside the nested folder and change the folder to an application (via IIS) everything works. But here's the thing:

For security reasons I'm not allowed to turn any nested folders on IIS into applications. I need to find a way to specify my login authetication tags inside the master web.config file, the one that's on my root folder.

When I try to do this, using the "location" tag to specify that I only need the login system in my nested folder:

```
  <location path="components/nestedFolder">
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Logon.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  </location>
```

...I get this obnoxious error:

> It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS.

As I said, there's no way I can turn my nested folder into an IIS application. So, is there a way to change the "allowDefinition" attribute so I can achieve my purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jose, I removed the C# tag only because this question is not a C# programming problem, it's an IIS configuration problem. Tags should be relevant to the question. You would have the same issue if your application was written in VB.NET as well.

Comment: The answer is you cannot.

Comment: What about the ConfigSections tag?

Comment: @JosePeres you can define new sections but cannot break existing ones.